# Using a SearchView to search in Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore, searchview

I have a searchview in my toolbar, and would like to use it to search some items in my firebase db and display them in the recyclerview.

I have tried multiple ways on SO already, but nothing seems to work.

Can anyone tell me how this could be accomplished?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please check the duplicate to see how it can be done.

Comment: @AlexMamo does this apply to Cloud Firestore ?

Comment: Yes, it also does apply to Cloud Firestore. Same principles apply.